# How to inflate buttons and create listeners for each one of them?

Tags: android, button, listener, layout-inflater, inflate

I want to create a variable number of buttons, and I want them to be adjacent (I cannot use the `ListView`), so I know I have to inflate a `Button` somehow. My question is how to inflate the `Button`, and for each of the created buttons, how to create a listener?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you're asking, but to inflate a button, in your activity, call:

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.layout_xml_name);
```

Then, to add a listener:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
    // Your buttons desired actions
    }
});
```

Comment: Inflating a layout is creating a new "instance" of that layout, well, that's what I know at least. Your code just retrieve the layout of a button, it doesn't inflate the button

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Are you trying to display different amounts of buttons based on some other input? And if so, is there a maximum number of buttons or unlimited?

Comment: well, that's right, I want to create a variable number of buttons and the number is unknown, can be limited.

Comment: My best suggestion would be put each button up to the limit in your layout, adding the attribute: `android:visibility="invisible"`. You can then later programmatically show it again by calling `mButton.setVisibility(VISIBLE)`. In the layout file, the _invisible_ attribute will hide the button, but the space will still be taken up. To utilize the space until it's needed for the button, you can use the _gone_ attribute instead.

Comment: I was just doing a little more research on the question and found [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7198409/2104186). I think this is more what you're looking for