# List of Strings in multiple buttons

Tags: android, list, button

I have a list of Strings (Video tags) and I wanna show each of them in a button (same as when you want to send a text for multiple users) and when I click on each an action happens for that box. I took a look at:

https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library

It generate each string in a box but finally I don't have access to specific item onclick.

Does anyone has any suggestion what to use or how to make it?!

Comment: Please show your code then we may suggest something.

Comment: @soulreaver I don't have a code for that yet. Imagine there is a ArrayList<String> and I want each item to be a Button and place after each other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195056/how-do-i-programmatically-add-buttons-into-layout-one-by-one-in-several-lines

Comment: @Rudi, have you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/about
what you want is creating a button programmatically ... http://bit.ly/17wycbp

Answer (score 0):

Read out the array of strings and
programmatically add a button with the text of each
string to for example a LinearLayout.

pseudo code:

```
ArrayList<string> list = getResources.array("id");

LinearLayout l = (Linearlayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
foreach(String s in list)
{
   l.addView(new Button(s));
}
```

Something like that.