# How to add views into several lines

Tags: android

I programmatically add a button (any view) into a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation.
How to make them be automatically placed on the next line?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195056/how-do-i-programmatically-add-buttons-into-layout-one-by-one-in-several-lines#comment8649980_7198409) is my question but without any answer.

Comment: If you need both horizontal and vertical orientation you will either need to wrap layouts (vertically oriented LinearLayout containing two horizontally oriented LinearLayouts) or use a RelativeLayout to explicitly declare how things should be laid out.

Comment: Do you mean android:layout_below="@+id/prevButtonId"?

Comment: You can use something like that in a relative layout if you want. Sure. I mean that's not the answer, but the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a `FlowLayout`, there are tremendous libraries around about this (ex. https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

Comment: Looks like it works.
Thank you!  
Strange that it needs to be added manually

Answer (score 0):

Make it with vertical orientation instead of horizontal.

Comment: I need a new line only after completing the previous